# Use of nextjs and middleware results in an uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token '<'

Tags: authentication, redirect, routes, next.js, middleware

I wrote a middleware in the nextjs app to redirect unauthenticated users to the login page. It redirects users but it leads to an error on console and shows a blank page. Is there any way to fix this?

- Here is my code on middleware.ts file:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export default function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    let hasToken = request.cookies.has('token')

    if (!hasToken && !request.url.includes('/login')) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
    }
    if (hasToken && request.url.includes('/login')) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
    }
    return NextResponse.next()
}
```

- and here is the error on console:

[uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token '<'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxtzJ.png)

Remove or altering the secoend item of the first condition, makes it work. e.g: change it to `(!hasToken && request.url.includes('/dashboard'))` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer, In new update of nextjs (12.2) middleware will be invoked for every route in your project([document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#matching-paths)).
So we have to set the specifier to limit the route we want. we can use "matcher" or a simple "if" statement to check the routes.
In my case both ways will work:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export default function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    let hasToken = request.cookies.has('token')

    if (request.url.includes('_next')) return // <============

    if (!hasToken && !request.url.includes('/login')) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
    }
    if (hasToken && request.url.includes('/login')) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
    }
    return NextResponse.next()
}
```

or using matcher:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export default function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    let hasToken = request.cookies.has('token')

    if (!hasToken && !request.url.includes('/login')) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
    }
    if (hasToken && request.url.includes('/login')) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
    }
    return NextResponse.next()
}

export const config = { // <============ 
    matcher: '/',
  }
```